# Cannot run "mvn jetty:run" in my fhir project

Tags: maven, hapi-fhir

Im new at fhir server.

My code mainly from repo https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter

I tried to install fhir server on my ubuntu 20.04(lts) and stuck with this problem.

my mvn version

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-50-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

ERROR

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The project ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter:war:6.2.1 uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------< ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter >------------
[INFO] Building HAPI FHIR JPA Server - Starter Project 6.2.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.48.v20220622:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @
 hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/root/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.8/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.8-runtime.jar=destfile=/root/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter/target/jacoco.exec,excludes=ca/uhn/fhir/model/dstu2/**/*.class:ca/uhn/fhir/jpa/rp/r5/*.class:ca/uhn/fhir/jpa/rp/r4/*.class:ca/uhn/fhir/jpa/rp/r4b/*.class:ca/uhn/fhir/jpa/rp/dstu3/*.class:ca/uhn/fhir/jpa/rp/dstu2/*.class,dumponexit=true
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 31 source files to /root/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.158 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-21T15:39:38Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Konfiguration on your system is wrong: `Unable to autodetect 'javac' path, using 'javac' from the environment.` ...

Comment: [UPDATE] I can fix the warning already by set path to environment but stuck at the same ERROR :(

Comment: If the error keeps. You have a compilation error in your code:  `hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter: Compilation failure`. as the message states...

Comment: [UPDATE] I added more information that maybe someone can help me with this error